# How to Find Edit Text Box and Spinner from dynamically created Can anyone

Tags: android, android-layout

Im not able to find out Spinner and Edit text in Layout

Code is as below It only Find Out EditText in Multiple Time

```
try {
                int count = my_linear_layout1.getChildCount();
                //EditText ed[] = new EditText[count];
                for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                    View row = my_linear_layout1.getChildAt(i);

                    row = my_linear_layout1.findFocus();
                    if(row instanceof EditText)
                    {
                        // you got the Edit Text  if (v.getClass().equals(TextView.class))
                        EditText textOut = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.OBSpn);
                        String data = textOut.getText().toString();
                    }

                    else if(row instanceof Spinner)
                    {
                        // you got the Spinner
                        Spinner Spin = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.SPNOBS);
                        String data1 = Spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    }

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Could not properly understand your question. Can you explain more

what you mean by 'It only calculates textview filed'..?

I could not find any TextViews in your xml.

Comment: Why dont you use a RecyclerView with an adapter.?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of LinearLayout, Use ListView. 
Follow this doc.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView

My question is why cant the ScrollView be the parent layout, relative layout is not needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"           
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/container"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               <ListView
                      android:id="@+id/list_view"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               </ListView>

               <!-- Add extra -->
       </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Comment: This is not feasible solution for me

Comment: Provide your requriements properly @Rahul Dhande Patil

Comment: Because I want to scroll that particular layout and other remains